# Is snow Kosher? Icicles?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, eating, snow

The recent snow storm got me thinking about this. So are you allowed to eat snow? What about icicles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wish that I could locate a definitive source to answer your question, but, in a way, the answer seems a rather obvious "yes it is kosher. My deduction:

Almost all drinking water occurs "naturally". If you or anyone else has hiked into a forest or anywhere that has a spring, esp. in the beginning of the Spring season, that water originated from snow that melted and seeped into the ground or flowed into a stream or river. Along the way, who knows what else may have gone into that stream - traces of animal feces, microorganisms (amoeba, hydra, etc.), perhaps traces of non-kosher pork chops from a camper's barbecue next to a stream somewhere. People either drink from the stream directly, or if buying bottled water, they're drinking that.

If you're wondering why does bottled water have a heksher, I asked someone from the OU a while ago and he explained that it has to do with the processing plant which may process other non-kosher products in the same plant. But spring water itself needs no heksher.

If you drink tap water, there's no heksher on that. (Yes, I know that there have been attempts to get one on NYC tap water, but so far, those efforts failed.)

I'm trying to make a "kal vachomer" in a way. If you're essentially drinking melted snow without a heksher, I think that whole unmelted snow doesn't need one. Granted, I don't recommend eating "dirty" snow from the street and certainly not from the road. Personally, the concern with such dirty snow is not its heksher but far worse - I don't recommend drinking a slush mix of gasoline and calcium chloride.

Comment: אל תאכל שלג צהוב as they say.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I don't know who says that, but, yes, yellow snow is probably not kosher except for the one who made it yellow.

Comment: @DanF I think it was Frank Zappa who popularized that phrase, but in English, not Hebrew.

Comment: @DanF the one who made it yellow is allowed to drink / eat it ?

Answer (score 2):

There is textual rabbinic evidence for the consumption of snow, and therefore its permissibility.

Eikhah 4:7

> זכו נזיריה משלג צחו מחלב אדמו עצם מפנינים ספיר גזרתם
>
> Her Nazirites were purer than snow, whiter than milk; their appearance
> was ruddier than gems, their form, a sapphire

[Eikhah Rabbah 4:10](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%93_%D7%99) writes:

> זכו נזיריה משלג אלו שהיו שותין את השלג
>
> Her Nazirites were purer than snow for they would consume snow.

The [Meshekh Hokhmah](https://www.sefaria.org/Meshekh_Chokhmah%2C_Eikhah.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains:

> מדרש זכו נזיריה משלג אלו שהיו שותין את השלג. פירוש שהיו נשמרין לאכול
> על טהרת תרומה טהרת הקודש... והשלג אינו מקבל טומאה שאינו אוכל ולא משקה כמפורש פ' כל
> היד (נדה י"ז ע"א), לכן שתו השלג.
>
> The Midrash stating "Her Nazirites were purer than snow for they would
> consume snow" the explanation for this is that they were careful in
> their consumption *'al taharath terumah taharath ha-qodesh*... and
> impurity does not devolve upon snow, since it is neither food nor
> drink as is explained in *Pereq Kol ha-Yad* (Niddah 17a), accordingly
> they would consume the snow.

See also H. [Tumath Okhalin 1:22](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=10&hilchos=61&perek=1&halocha=22&hilite=)

From the fact that a Nazir, whose diet is even more restricted than most, we see that consuming snow is not only permissible but under certain halakhic circumstances may even be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a source to the excellent answers above: Iyov 9:30 seems to make the point that snow is kosher, and especially pure:

‘Even if I bathed in liquid snow, and were pure down to my hands, You would plunge me into the pit until even my clothes detested me.’ (Koren translation).